# My Simple Spark job failed with error : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, pycharm

I am new to Spark.(Pyspark 3.4 and Python 3.12)
I have a very simple LOC as below(in Pycharm), but I am getting the error **org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)**
Whole code runs fine but at show command it throws the error. Please help, incase some1faced same issue:

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

spark=SparkSession.builder.appName("test1").config("spark.driver.host", "localhost").config("spark.memory.offHeap.enabled","true").config("spark.memory.offHeap.size","10g").getOrCreate()

sc=spark.sparkContext
dept = [("1","2")]
df = spark.createDataFrame(dept, [("id")])
df.show()
```